# Netsuite Error While Uploading SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to upload a basic Hello World **suitescript** into **netsuite** and am receiving this error:

> Fail to evaluate script:

```
{
    "type": "error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError",
    "name": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
    "message": "missing } after property list (SS_SCRIPT_FOR_METADATA#29)",
    "stack": []
}
```

Code below:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 *@NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/ui/dialog'], 
    function(dialog) {
        function helloWorld() {
            var options = {
                title: 'Hello!',
                message: "Hello, world!"
            };
            try {
                dialog.alert(options);
                log.debug({
                    title: 'Success',
                    details: 'Alert displayed successfully'
                });

            } catch (e) {
                log.error({
                    title: 'Failure',
                    details: 'Alert displayed unsuccessfully'
                });
            }
        }
        return {
            pageInit: helloWorld
        };
    });
```

Can anyone provide any suggestion?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find anything wrong in your script.
Please try using different file name but same code.
Try creating new script record and deployment.

Comment: while this is a fix I have provided the reason that a user might see that issue which would also serve as a 'fix'.   Changing from 2.0 to 2.1 to allow for the keyword to be recognized.   People may do well to be aware of it in case they are trying to edit old scripts that were 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you were seeing here is that you were using 2.0 as a definition and that does not support the use of let.   2.1 does because it is base on  ECMAScript 2018 (ES2018) but 2.0 was using ES 5.1.   (let was not introduced till ES6).

Comment: Yes, this. Sadly NetSuite errors are hardly useful when it comes to failing for using unsupported features.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've run into this before. 
The JSDoc goes with the define function so the extra line between the end of the JSDoc and the define causes some parsing issue.

Change:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 *@NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/ui/dialog'],
```

to

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 *@NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/ui/dialog'],
```

Comment: I was able to upload this both with and without the space.  I think SuiteScript upload was doing something when I tried to upload it initially.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error:

```
Fail to evaluate script: 
{
    "type":"error.SuiteScript ModuleLoader Error",
    "name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
    "message":"missing ; before statement (SS_SCRIPT_FOR_METADATA#23)",
    "stack":[]
}
```

I solved it by changing the variables declaration from "let" to "var". SuiteScripts version 2.x does not support "let".